# can i use document.form_name.input_name for referencing that element?

Tags: javascript, reference

Can I use `document.form_name.input_name` for referencing that element?

For example,

```
<form name="form_name">
<input name="input_name" />
<input name="input_name2 />
</form>
```

I wrote the above code, and I want to reference the form element.

I saw in many documents that we should use `document.forms['form_name'].input_name`,
but when I tried `document.form_name.input_name`, it works.

But I think the last way makes me feel uncomfortable.

So, can I use it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use that, as long as you don't want it to work in all browsers. There are a few ways to access elements in JavaScript. For example, if you want the name of your first input field, you can use `document.forms[0].elements[0].name` or `document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].name` or `document.getElementsByName("input_name")[0].name`. If you're looking for simplicity and code that looks more intuitive than plain JavaScript, try jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

document.form_name.input_name can be used .

but if you want to support all browsers ,better use [document.getElementsByTagName](http://www.w3schools.com/dom/met_document_getelementsbytagname.asp).

or u can use any [javascript based frameworks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category%3aJavaScript_libraries) and that is the best way.